# Python - How to find a number in a list

Tags: python, list

...that is less than or equal to another number?

Eg,

```
a = [2, 5, 6, 9]
b = 3
```

How will I be able to get the number less than or equal to 3 within list `a`?

Comment: well maybe see each number inside the list and compare to 3?

Comment: Search the web for "python bisect"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## print the numbers less than b in the list a

```
a = [2, 5, 6, 9]
b = 3
for num in a: 
    if num <= b: 
        print num
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [list comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html#list-comprehensions) for this, 
[image]

```
>>>a = [2, 5, 6, 9]
>>>b = 3
>>>[x for x in a if x<=b]
>>>[2]
```

If you want to sorted list,

```
sortedList = sorted(x for x in a if x <= b)
```

or sort after the list creation,

```
>>>myList = [x for x in a if x <= b]
>>>myList.sort()
```

Using [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter),

```
>>>filter(lambda x: x <= b, a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort it and loop over it-

```
a = sorted(a)
for value in b:
    if value <= number: # 3
        print(value)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this -

```
c = [i for i in a if i <= b]
```

Answer (score 0):

simply filter with lambdas.

```
filter(lambda x: x>3, [2,5,6,9])
# [5, 6, 9]
filter(lambda x: x<3, [2,5,6,9])
# [2]
```

http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php